# How do i make some groupboxes in my panel appear faded and not hided?

Tags: c#, winforms, groupbox

I have a panel with three groupboxes. Each groupbox has its control(combobox, labels, textboxes etc.). Groupbox1 is default when the panel is loaded. A combobox with two items determines when groupbox2 becomes visible while groupbox1 disappear so that the user can input certain information in it.

from properties, groupbox1: visible = "true"        groupbox2: visible = "false"           groupbox3: visible = "false"

My intention is that,

1) Item one does nothing when selected since default groupbox1 and its controls are already visible.

2) Item two makes groupbox1 and its controls hidden and groupbox2 and its controls visible. A combobox with similiar function is in groupbox2 exist to enable the switch back to the groupbox1 is item two is selected.

All this is supposed to occurs during runtime.

There is a third groupbox3 which is triggered by a button on the panel. I intend to make the groupbox3 visible whilst making everything on the panel look dim until a close button is clicked on groupbox3. i want to be able to make changes in the labels in groupbox1 and groupbox2 using a combobox control in groupbox3.

My Problem is

1)how do i make groupbox1 or groupbox2 on the panel appear faded and not totally hidden, while groupbox3 pops up like a messagebox,and also when i click a close button on groupbox3, groupbox3 closes while groupbox1 or groupbox2 becomes visible again.

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gb1.Visible = cb1.SelectedIndex == 0;

        switch (cb1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                gb1.Visible = true;
                gb2.Visible = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                gb2.Visible = true;
                gb1.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gb2.Visible = cb2.SelectedIndex == 0;

        switch (cb1.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                gb2.Visible = true;
                gb1.Visible = false;
                break;
            case 1:
                gb1.Visible = true;
                gb2.Visible = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    private void bt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gb3.Show();
        gb1.Hide();
        gb2.Hide();
    }

    private void bt2_on_gb3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gb3.Hide();
        gb1.Show();
        gb2.Show();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Also, the title doesn't really fit the post because, you ask in the title how to make the second group box visible and the default, aka 1st, as written in your post, hidden/invisible, yet in the post you already answered this question because you write: `Item one does nothing when selected since default groupbox1 and its controls are already visible. Item two makes groupbox1 and its controls hidden and groupbox2 and its controls visible.`, or am I missing something?

Comment: the highlighted section is my intention

Answer (score 0):

The question is still a little unclear, but here's a shot:

## Fading

### Solution 1

Consider using the `Enabled` property. This makes the controls in the group box appear faded. That said, its primary function is to prevent the user from interacting with them. You can still change values programatically though. See the second example if don't want to disable the controls.

#### Example 1

```
    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gb1.Enabled = cb1.SelectedIndex == 0;
        gb1.Enabled = cb1.SelectedIndex == 1;

        // Unless you plan to add more cases to the switch,
        // the switch is redundant with the lines above.
        //switch (cb1.SelectedIndex)
        //{
        //    case 0:
        //        gb1.Enabled = true;
        //        gb2.Enabled = false;
        //        break;
        //    case 1:
        //        gb2.Enabled = true;
        //        gb1.Enabled = false;
        //        break;
        //}
    }
```

### Solution 2

I wasn't sure, but it almost seems like you were looking to simply perform a visual only dimming of the controls (and not block the user from interacting with them), you can experiment with the `ForeColor` property on each individual control. You could set and restore the ForeColor individually per control or you could do this with by looping through the Controls Collection of the GroupBox. Note that the loop is probably only helpful if all the controls in the group have the same initial forecolor (which you also may want to store so you can restore it).

That said, this is non-standard WinForms behavior and may confuse users.

#### Example 2

```
    public static readonly Color kFadedColor = Color.DarkGray;

    private void SetGroupBoxContentsForeColor(GroupBox aGroupbox, Color aColor)
    {
        aGroupbox.ForeColor = aColor;

        foreach (Control lControl in aGroupbox.Controls)
        {
            lControl.ForeColor = aColor;
        }
    }

    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Again, if you need to expand the ComboBox entries,
        // this will need additional logic
        if (cb1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            SetGroupBoxContentsForeColor(gb1, mPrevioslySavedColorToRestore);
            SetGroupBoxContentsForeColor(gb2, kFadedColor);
        }
        else
        {
            SetGroupBoxContentsForeColor(gb2, mPrevioslySavedColorToRestore);
            SetGroupBoxContentsForeColor(gb1, kFadedColor);
        }
    }
```

### Solution 3

Also non-standard, but perhaps you want to highlight the groupbox instead.

#### Example 3

```
    public static readonly Color kHighlightedColor = Color.Orange;

    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Again, if you need to expand the ComboBox entries,
        // this will need additional logic
        if (cb1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            gb1.ForeColor = kHighlightedColor;
            gb2.ForeColor = mPrevioslySavedColorToRestore;
        }
        else
        {
            gb2.ForeColor = kHighlightedColor;
            gb1.ForeColor = mPrevioslySavedColorToRestore;
        }
    }
```

*Notes:*

The original `cb2_SelectedIndexChanged()` method is using `switch (cb1.SelectedIndex)` instead of `switch (cb2.SelectedIndex)`

## ComboBox3 and GroupBox3

### Solution

Assuming you want disable the controls to fade them (Fading Solution 1 above), you can do the following. However, you may need to add additional
logic to check the state of ComboBoxes `cb1` and `cb2` if that is important.

Also, if you need `gb3` hidden to start with, either set the `Visible` property in the WinForms designer, or set `gb3.Visible = false;` in the Forms constructor following the `InitializeComponent()` method call.

#### Example

```
    private void BtnShowGB3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable/fade gb1 and gb2
        gb1.Enabled = false;
        gb2.Enabled = false;
        // Make gb3 visible
        gb3.Visible = true;
    }

    private void BtnHideGB3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable/unfade gb1 and gb2
        gb1.Enabled = true;
        gb2.Enabled = true;
        // Hide gb3
        gb3.Visible = false;
    }
```